# Get files from a directory excluding the files from another list?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code:

```
private void CreateNewGif(string urlsdirs)
{
    List<string> files = Directory.GetFiles(urlsdirs, "RainImage*.*").ToList();
    List<string> files1 = Directory.GetFiles(urlsdirs, "SatelliteImage*.*").ToList();
}
```

files contain 62 files. files1 contain only 9 files.
I need that files will contain the number of files minus the length of the second List.

For example in files i have 62 files for example:

```
index 0: file000001
index 1: file000002
.
.
.
index 61: file000062
```

files contain another files for example:

```
index 0: test000001
index 1: test000002
.
.
.
index 8: test000009
```

So I need that the List files1 will contain file000001 and file000002....but only 53 files instead 62 files in the original.

I need to make somehow the `files1.length` - `files.length` but not as math 62 - 9 but to also remove the first 9 files from the `files1` List.

So in the end the List file1 will contain only 53 files. ( 62 - `files.length` )

So now if i will look at the list `files1` i will see that it will start from 10 to 62.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
var satelliteImages = Directory.GetFiles(urlsdirs, "SatelliteImage*.*");
var suffixes = satelliteImages.Select(s => s.Substring(14));
var hashSet = new HashSet(suffixes);
var rainImages = Directory.GetFiles(urlsdirs, "RainImage*.*");
var filteredImages = rainImages.Where(s => !hashSet.Contains(s.Substring(9)))
var files = filteredImages.ToList();
```

Explanation:

1. Get the list of all `"SatelliteImage*.*"` files you want to exclude.
2. Select the suffix of the file name that you're interested in
   <sup>(Note: `s.Substring(14)` because `"SatelliteImage".Length = 14"`)</sup>
3. Turn the suffixes into a `HashSet` for fast look up.
4. Get the list of all `"RainImage*.*"` files.
5. Filter out items that have a suffix that appears in the `HashSet`.
   <sup>(Note: `s.Substring(9)` because `"RainImage".Length = 9"`)</sup>
6. Finally, turn the result into a list.

Or to make it a little more brief:

```
var hashSet = new HashSet(Directory.GetFiles(urlsdirs, "SatelliteImage*.*").Select(s => s.Substring(14)));
var files = Directory.GetFiles(urlsdirs, "RainImage*.*").Where(s => !hashSet.Contains(s.Substring(9))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var result = files.OrderBy(x => x).Skip(files1.Count);
```